# Bean Validation List<?> on static method or getters

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

I have a problem of triggering the custom constraint validation on jersey. I would like to activate the constraint on a method or a static method. What I have tried is putting a custom annotation and `@ValidateOnExecution` on top of the method, but the custom validator class still was not triggered.

```
@LocationIsValid
@ValidateOnExecution
public static List<Double> getLocation(String location) {
   ...
}
```

I suspected that the problem is bean annotation did not support static method, so I removed the static keyword and accessing the method by creating a new object. However the custom `LocationIsValid` validator still was not activated.

As a result I ended up placing a validator factory to validate this variable manually.

```
public static List<Double> getLocation(String location) {
   ...
   // split the location string into a list of double
   ...
   ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
   validator = factory.getValidator();
   validator.validate(location, LocationIsValid.class);
}
```

But yet the custom constraints won't budge. I hope that someone can give me a clue on what to do next, or other suggestion on solving this issue.

**More Info**

It works properly when the annotation is placed on top of the resource field.

```
public class Product {

    ... 

    @LocationIsValid
    private List<Double> location;

    ...

}
```

**Updated**

Even I have changed the method to normal instance method, it still doesn't work. Note that I have two overloaded methods, one is the resource getter, the other one is for converting the string to locations.

Product model

```
public class Product {

@Id
@JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdSerializer.class)
private ObjectId id;
@Size(min = 5)
private String name;
@NotNull
@LocationIsValid
private List<Double> location;

private Date dateCreated;

private Date dateModified;

public Product() {

}

public List<Double> getLocation() {
    return location;
}

@ValidateOnExecution
@LocationIsValid
public List<Double> getLocation(String location) {
    String[] locationString = location.split(";");

    if (locationString.length != 2) {
        return null;
    }

    List<Double>locations = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationString.length; i++) {
        locations.add(Double.parseDouble(locationString[i]));
    }
    return locations;
} 


// Other setters getters

}
```

Product resource

```
@GET
public ProductList getProducts(@QueryParam("near") String location) {
    // parse the locations variable
    Product product = new Product();
    // did not work
    // I have placed a breakpoint on the LocationIsValid
    List<Double> locations = product.getLocation(location);
}
```

Note: I am pretty sure the problem is not located in LocationIsValid, as it works correctly when I validated it as an entity `@Valid Product product` I am using Jersey 2.4.1 with jersey-bean-validation 2.4.1 dependency

Comment: Are other constraints working properly?

Comment: it works properly when the annotation is placed on the field, which is the resource variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I did not actually invoke the validator using `@Valid` at the Product object in the controller. The reason is I only need to validate the location variable and not the whole Product object. So I guess the only way to solve it is to invoke the validator factory programatically inside the resource function. Note that the reason I did not success validate the property using the validator before is because I never call the correct method. Below is the code that make use of validation factory to validate a specific property in a resource object.

```
@GET
public ProductList getProducts(@QueryParam("near") String location) {
  // parse the locations variable
  List<Double> locations = Product.getLocation(location);
  // validate the value
  Set<ConstraintViolation<Product>> constraints = Validation
    .buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator()
    .validateValue(Product.class, "location", locations, Default.class);
    if (locations == null || locations.size() != 2
        || constraints.size() > 0) {
        throw new ConstraintViolationException(constraints);
    }
}
```

If someone has better ideas or suggestions to workaround with this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As you say validation of static methods is not supported by the Bean Validation specification. The validation of instance methods should work though, can you post the entire code of your JAX-RS resource? Is `getLocation()` defined on that resource? JAX-RS should trigger the validation of method constraints (be it parameter or return value constraints) on the methods of resource classes.

Comment: yeah I have two `getLocation()` methods, one is for the resource, the other one is for parsing. I have updated the question.

Comment: I guess the problem is the method was not triggered at all at the first time, because it works when I set it as `@Valid Product product`. But then how can I validate only the specific method?